# Selenium - How to debug timeout for iframe > input field?

Tags: python, iframe, selenium

I'm stuck writing a Selenium WebDriver script for Instagram web login. I think I switched to the appropriate iframe but WebDriver keeps timing out when it should locate the user input field.

**Relevant source from Instagram site:**

```
https://instagram.com/accounts/login/
<iframe class="hiFrame" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.1.0.0.$frame"    src="https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/?targetOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com" scrolling="no" seamless="">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="hl-en not-logged-in " lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="LoginFormChrome ">
<div class="LoginFormPage" data-reactid=".0">
<form data-reactid=".0.0">
<p class="lfField" data-reactid=".0.0.0">
<label class="lfFieldLabel" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0">
<input class="lfFieldInput" type="text" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1" value="" autocorrect="false" autocapitalize="false" maxlength="30" name="username">
</p>
```

**Source from Selenium script:**

```
login_url = 'https://instagram.com/accounts/login/'
profile_url = '<path_firefix_profile>'
user = '<user_name>'
#login
my_profile = FirefoxProfile(profile_url)
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(my_profile)

self.driver.get(login_url)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
my_iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe.hiFrame")
#my_iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe:nth-of-type(1)")
#my_iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
self.driver.switch_to_frame(my_iframe)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
    user_input = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
    user_input.send_keys(user)
finally:
    print('user name input appeared')
```

**Results:**
This error results from WebDriver:
File "instagram_firefox.py", line 51, in setUp
    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 45).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message)

I tried to verify that the css selector for the input field was correct. On the page, https://instagram.com/accounts/login/, FireFox FireFinder does not recognize the css selector that I used. But if I open another tab with the source of the iframe, https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/?targetOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Finstagram.com, then Firefinder recognizes the css selector that I used. Does this mean I need to manually get the url of the iframe source or should that be done automatically when WebDriver switches to the iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should wait first for `div` spinner element to disappear, then we can retrieve that iframe you need:

```
user = "user"
self.driver.get("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/")
#Wait for spinner to disappear
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.liSpinnerLayer")))
#Get iframe and switch to it
my_iframe = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe.hiFrame")
self.driver.switch_to_frame(my_iframe)
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
element.send_keys(user)
```